# How do I solve $E\left[ E \left(X|Z \right) E\left( Y|Z \right)\right]$?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am trying to solve $E\left[ E \left( \mathbf{X}|\mathbf{Z} \right) E \left( \mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{Z} \right) \right]$, (where $\mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{Y}$, and $\mathbf{Z}$ are random variables) but I am confused - should the solution be $E \left( \mathbf{X}\mathbf{Y} \right)$ or $E\left(\mathbf{X} \right)E\left(\mathbf{Y}\right)$. Any explanation as to why this way or the other will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Have you worked out a simple example, such as a case where $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ can attain at most two distinct values each?

Comment: Here's another hint: try $X=Y=Z$.

Comment: Does your book say that $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$?